# Creating a new variable automatically - Generating a variable - Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, metaprogramming, generate

Meta info: Found similar posts, zero were for Ruby.
Created title using multiple terms for search accessibility

Okay now onto the question...
I'm trying to generate new variables (moreso) automatically, I wanted to create a mechanism that did so.

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
  @name = name
  end

end

def CreateUser(name)
  name = User.new(name)
end

CreateUser("Arnold")
p Arnold
```

I used a single argument in the name parameter of method "CreateUser" as both the name of the variable that I want to declare and the information sent into the code creating a member of my class.

I quickly remembered that in Ruby, variables inside of  a method are local to only the method. If that weren't the case, and I could spit out the new variable from the method then I could generate my users easily - but this isn't the case. Is there a work around for this? Or is declaring a new variable manually just the name of the game?

Comment: Do you want `Arnold` to be a its own constant, such as a class/struct as it appears in your example? There are a few different ways to accomplish that if so. Should `Arnold` be an instance of `User`, or its own class derived from `User`?

Comment: declaring a new variable manualy really is the "name of the game" truth be told. Technically you can define a new global variable anywhere using `Object.const_set` but it's not a good practice. What if you have the users with the same name? You can only have the variable pointing to one of them. And what if a user has a name conflicting with another constant (e.g. someone named "String")? Generally constants (variables starting with capital letters) aren't defined dynamically anyway, it kindd of conflicts with the notion of a "constant"

Comment: Since Ruby version 1.8.7 it has not been possible to create local variables dynamically; instance variables, yes, local variables, no.

Comment: ForeverZer0 - Arnold should be an instance of User
MaxPleaner - So, what if I create a different mechanism for creating the variable name? Say a random_ID_generator method that creates a randomized string of letters/numbers, that also checks to see if it is unique? Wouldn't something like that work? I'd like to learn more about Object.const_set because it sounds like what I'm looking for.
Cary - I see.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little confusing. At first glance, it seems like you're looking for some metaprogramming technique to dynamically create instance variables, such as:

```
class User
  def new_variable name, value
      instance_variable_set "@#{name}", value
  end
end
```

However, upon looking more closely at the problem you're actually trying to solve, it seems like the real issue is that you aren't making your methods part of your original object. This is probably what you really want:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize name
    @name = name
  end 

  def create_user
    # do whatever you need to do to "create" a user
    pp name
  end
end

u = User.new 'Arnold'
u.create_user
```

Enabling an object to call instance methods on data stored within the object is part of *encapsulation*. That is most likely what you're really after.

Comment: Hmm, not quite, you still declaring the variable by writing u = User.new... That's what I was trying to avoid. I'm basically looking for a way to generate variables without declaring them. Like a factory conveyor belt that can just pump them out, one after another, each time some method is called.

I know there has to be a way, because they do this in a framework every time a new user is created, using a Create function of a C.R.U.D., no?

Comment: @Nick No. Point to a framework that does that. If you mean you want to create a User object and assign a name later because *name* is optional, that's one thing. And if you mean you want to create an object with dynamic members, maybe look at OpenStruct.

Comment: @Nick most frameworks with "CRUD" logic use data storage (e.g. database or files) to "create". The lifecycle of these objects tends to be ephemeral while their data retains permanence through the storage facility and can be re instantiated via a data retrieval mechanism (query, parsing, etc.)